# How do I create SQL connection to my app and Upload it to google cloud

Tags: sql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Thanks for getting back at me. Sorry for the late reply, it was bed-time this time. I need to connect the Cloud SQL database that I have created to my application that is in App Engine. I tried to follow the online tutorials but when I do apply such info I would get then *gcloud app deploy* it return a connection error. Please help. Also clarify here: When I execute the gcloud  app deploy command I suppose it takes my local file to Google Cloud where I would see the entire folder and files of my project on the project I was deploying but I am seeing the old version of my project while presentation has changed to the latest version. Also last one how can I link domain nam from http://domain.google.com  to my app in http://cloud.google.com . Please help I am dying with stress I have been trying in here

Comment: Can you please post your app.yaml contents? Obviously get rid of anything sensitive.

Comment: runtime: nodejs
env: flex
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: <cloud_sql_instance_id>=tcp:3306

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have been out of internet at Home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you haven't provided any information as to what settings you are using, or what error has been provided it is impossible to know what kind of problem you are running into.

I suggest taking a look at the "Connecting to App Engine" page [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine). It should answer a lot of your questions around connecting from an App Engine app.

Comment: Hi Kurtisvg, The error is: 
Hi Rojas, I am still encountering an error on connection.  

Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and will not scale past a single process. 

my app.yaml looks as follow:
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME> 

my connection on the server is as:

var connection = mysql.createConnection
({
  host     : 'port number',
  user     : 'user',
  password : password here",
  database : 'db name',
  charset : 'utf8mb4'
});

Comment: Thanks I managed to solve it, it was socketpath which I didnt include, can you help me in this one now.

Comment: This is the one error I just got now: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myplusplus.net/user/login' from origin 'https://myplusplus-web.appspot.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: @FezekilePlaatyi I'm glad my answer helped resolve your problem. Please make sure to upvote (or accept) answers that are helpful to you.

A CORS problem is a different question - I suggest you ask another question with appropriate tags and hopefully someone will be able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I see two questions here.

1.

> I need to connect the Cloud SQL database that I have created to my
>   application that is in App Engine. I tried to follow the online
>   tutorials but when I do apply such info I would get then gcloud app
>   deploy it return a connection error. Please help. Also clarify here:
>   When I execute the gcloud app deploy command I suppose it takes my
>   local file to Google Cloud where I would see the entire folder and
>   files of my project on the project I was deploying but I am seeing the
>   old version of my project while presentation has changed to the latest
>   version.

I see your problem here to be with CloudSQL and GAE connectivity. Depending on whether you use GAE Standard or Flex and CloudSQL MySQL or POSTGRES the steps varies. Documentation is quite clear in here though.

2.

> Also last one how can I link domain nam from http://domain.google.com
>   to my app in http://cloud.google.com . Please help I am dying with
>   stress I have been trying in here

This is going to be super simple, goto GCP cloud console, Navigate to GAE-->Settings-->Custom Domain and click on add custom domain "Enter the domain name you want to link" When you click continue you will be shown the steps for verifying the domain owneship and to point the DNS to the GAE.
Documented properly by GCP folks at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains

Comment: Thanks, Madan the mapping to my custom domain just worked. Highly appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GAE Standard or Flex, a possible result of command gcloud app deploy :
An app.yaml (or appengine-web.xml) file is required to deploy this directory as an App Engine App, check next links:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/writing-application-logs

Mysql and Postgres connection:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine

Sometimes it easy share the app.yaml for replicate the app correctly.

Comment: This is the one error I just got now: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myplusplus.net/user/login' from origin 'https://myplusplus-web.appspot.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.